# Why is powershell switching directories mid code on copy-item when the variable is already defined?

Tags: powershell

I have some code that checks a target file, waits for a change, and I want it to only move the most recent files based on their LastWriteTime Value. However, every time I change a file within the target directory nothing is copying over and I am having the copy-item directory change to "C:\Users\run". I

it recognizes that there are files to copy and even states their filename when throwing the error. What can I do in this situation to make sure my copy-item command is copying from my target directory?

Code for Reference:

```
    $File = "C:\Users\run\Desktop\Target"
    $destinationFolder = "c:\users\run\desktop\dest"
    
    
    $maxDays = "-1"
    $maxMins = "20"
    $date = Get-Date
    
    Write-Host "Waiting For File To Change in Job Cloud..."
    
    
    $Action = '
    dateChecker
    Write-Host "Moving Files From Job Cloud To Server Shares... Please Do Not Disrupt This Service"
    write-host "files copied to job cloud..."
    exit
    '
    
    $global:FileChanged = $false
    
    
    function dateChecker {
        Foreach($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $File)){
            if($File.LastWriteTime -lt ($date).AddMinutes($maxMins)){
               Write-Host "Moving Files From Job Cloud To Server Shares... Please Do Not Disrupt This Service"
               Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $destinationFolder -recurs #-ErrorAction #silentlyContinue
               }
    }
    }
        
    
    
    
    while($true) {
    function Wait-FileChange {
        param(
            [string]$File,
            [string]$Action
        )
        $FilePath = Split-Path $File -Parent
        $FileName = Split-Path $File -Leaf
        $ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($Action)
    
        $Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $FilePath, $FileName -Property @{ 
            IncludeSubdirectories = $false
            EnableRaisingEvents = $true
        }
        $onChange = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Changed -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true}
    
        while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
            
        }
    
        & $ScriptBlock 
        Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $onChange.Id
        
       
    }
    
    Wait-FileChange -File $File -Action $Action
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Change `Copy-Item -Path $File` to `Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName` or `$File |Copy-Item`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is not switching directories - although I can certainly see why you'd think that based on the behavior. The explanation is closer than you might think though:

The `-Path` parameter takes a `[string]` argument.

`$File` is *not* a string - it's a `[FileInfo]` object - and PowerShell therefore converts it to a string before passing it to `Copy-Item -Path`. Unfortunately, this results in the *name* of the file (not the full path) being passed as the argument, and `Copy-Item` therefore has to resolve the full path, and does so relative to the current working directory.

You can fix this by passing the full path explicitly to `Copy-Item -LiteralPath`:

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName ... |...
```

or you can let the pipeline parameter binder do it for you by piping the `$File` object to `Copy-Item`:

```
$File |Copy-Item ... |...
```

---

Why `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`? `-Path` accepts wildcard patterns like `filenameprefix[0-9]` and tries to resolve it to a file on disk, meaning if you have to operate on files with `[` or `]` in the name, it'll result in some unexpected behavior :)